# Connecting PHP application to MS Sql Server on prem

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database-connection, sqlsrv

I am developing an application to upload data throught PHP to a SQL DB stored in a MS Sql Server on prem. The main problem I am having right now, is that i am not able to connect my application to the server, using sqlsrv_connect, and everytime I run a query with that application I get 502 bad gateway. Is there something i need to install to php or to the sql server to make the application work?
Thank you for your help
p.s. I inserted the code snippet below

```
 <?php 
$serverName = "";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
    echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you have the https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php extension loaded?

Answer (score 0):

First install the [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) and then check the [Getting started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#getting-started) section which gives you info about how to connect.